# MVC Store is not loaded

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, proxy, sencha-touch, store

I am new to SenchaTouch, trying to create an MVC based app with the help of docs.

Now am stuck in loading store dynamically from a service.

I went through many links/discussion for the same but those are implemented in different ways.

Please help me to solve this and suggest is it right way implementation of MVC in senchatouch.

Here is my code.

Contronller:

```
        var store1 = Ext.create('x.store.edAuthenticateStore',{});
        store1.setProxy({
            type:'ajax',
            url:'AppURL',
            reader:{
                type:'xml',
                rootProperty:"mbsResponse"
            },
            autoLoad:true
        });
        store1.load();

        alert(store1.getModel().get('membername'));
```

Store:

```
    Ext.define('x.store.edAuthenticateStore',{
         extend:'Ext.data.Store',
         requires:['Ext.data.reader.Xml'],
         config:{
             storeId:'authStore',
             model:'edTouch.model.edAuthenticateUserResult'
         }
    });
```

Models:

```
    //1) edAuthenticateUserResult'
    Ext.define('edTouch.model.edAuthenticateUserResult',{
         extend:'Ext.data.Model',
         config:{
             id:'edAuthResult',
             fields:[
                {name:'memberid', type:'string'},
                {name:'membername', type:'string'},
                {name:'mbsstatuscode', type:'string'}, 
                {name:'mbsstatustext', type:'string'}
             ],
             hasMany:{
                     model:'edTouch.model.edChild',
                     name:'children'
             },
             hasOne:{
                 model:'edTouch.model.edSchoolDetails',
                 name:'schoolDetails'
             }      

         }
    });
    //2) edChild
    Ext.define('x.model.edChild',{
         extend:'Ext.data.Model',
         config:{
            fileds :[
              {name:'studentid', type:'string'},
              {name:'firstname', type:'string'},
              {name:'lastname' ,type:'string'},
              {name:'rollnumber', type:'string'},
              {name:'classid', type:'string'},
              {name:'classname', type:'string'},
              {name:'sectionid', type:'string'},
              {name:'sectionname', type:'string'},
              {name:'imagepath', type:'string'},                
            ]
        }
    });
    //3)
    Ext.define('x.model.edSchoolDetails',{
        extend:'Ext.data.Model',
        config:{
            fields:[           
              {name:'schoolid', type:'string'},
              {name:'schoolname', type:'string'},
              {name:'schoolImage' ,type:'string'},
              {name:'schoolweburl', type:'string'},
              {name:'location', type:'string'}
            ]
        }
     });
```

_ xml ***_*_**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<authenticateUserResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <authenticateUserResult>
    <mbsResponse xmlns="">
      <mbsstatuscode>200</mbsstatuscode>
      <mbsstatustext>Success</mbsstatustext>
      <memberid>101</memberid>
      <membername>xyz</membername>
      <schoolDetails>
        <schoolid>5</schoolid>
        <schoolname>abacd</schoolname>
        <schoolImage>123.jpg</schoolImage>
        <schoolweburl>www.google.com</schoolweburl>
        <location>IND</location>
      </schoolDetails>
      <children>
        <child>
          <studentid>1</studentid>
          <firstname>FName</firstname>
          <lastname>M</lastname>
          <rollnumber>123001</rollnumber>
          <classid>1</classid>
          <classname>1ST CLASS</classname>
          <sectionid>1</sectionid>
          <sectionname>A</sectionname>
          <imagepath>201312210145183111226-151723.jpg</imagepath>
        </child>
      </children>
    </mbsResponse>
  </authenticateUserResult>
</authenticateUserResponse>
```

Comment: What is error you are getting ?? Have you gone through this documentation ?? http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/class_system

Comment: its not giving any error. But when try to call any getter on model [ which got from store ] giving undefined.

Comment: Please help to solve the issue

Comment: I have found and example of MVC store using sencha ...Here is  the link http://www.senchafiddle.com/#b4K8w#rYgdP  Go through it and c if it fulfills ur requirement..Meanwhile i will also try..

Comment: In this example its not showing how data is loaded. But here its showing to access data, the same way i tried to get but am getting data count as 0 on store.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

`store1.load();`

with

```
store1.load({
    scope   : this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        // check for success and set the value of button        
    }
});
```

Comment: Its not entering into the callback function.

Comment: is it wrong way implementation of MVC or any problem in mapping models….please help me to understand this.

Comment: Have you gone through this links http://css.dzone.com/articles/writing-sencha-touch-mvc  And also try this example on github  https://github.com/pmeinhardt/sencha-touch-mvc/tree/master/app/controllers